# Python. Как из ссылки достать имя файла с расширением

Tags: python, ссылка

Есть тестовая ссылка `url = 'https://example.com/txt/hello%20world.txt?v=9#python'`. Необходимо максимально коротким способом достать из неё имя файла с расширением.

Мой способ :

```
unquoted_url = unquote_plus(string=url, encoding='utf-8', errors='Replace')
filename = os.path.basename(unquoted_url).split('?')[0]
```

Вопрос: есть ли ещё более короткий метод? И чтоб не спотыкался о пробелы, якорь, GET-параметры.

Comment: Ну, если формат всегда такой, то регуляркой между / и GET параметрами (или концом строки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
from urllib import parse

unquoted_url = parse.unquote("https://example.com/txt/hello%20world.txt?v=9#python")
path = parse.urlparse(unquoted_url).path

print(path.rstrip("/").split("/")[-1])
```

- *path* здесь это: `/txt/hello world.txt`
- *rstrip* я вызываю для обеспечения корректной работы при обработке *url*, заканчивающихся на `/` (например, `https://example.com/`). Иначе, вы получите лишь пустую строку
- Далее, просто делю по `/` и беру последний элемент списка

*STDOUT*:

```
hello world.txt
```